# WindowsError: [Error 127] The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, ctypes

What does this error mean?  I have trouble googling any docs.   The code worked fine and suddenly broke after restarting windows.   I looked in the process monitor and the DLL is found and accessed without any permission errors

```
  File "c:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 435, in __getattr__
    dll = self._dlltype(name)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 127] The specified procedure could not be found
```

Comment: Could be the same problem: [LoadLibrary() error code 127](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1053180/222914)

Comment: it does look like some kind of DLL conflict but so far I was not able to trace it. it's a Windows madness.

Answer (score 5):

I have faced the same problem while working with Python 2.7 and this is what I found:

-- Problem was coming because I have **installed multiple versions of python** (Python3.2, Python3.5 etc).

-- Because of multiple versions, at runtime there was multiple DLLs with same name (in all python versions library). So it was **unable to figure out which one to load**.

**Solution**:
-- I have uninstalled all python versions except one I needed (Python2.7) at time. Then run the program and then everything was working fine for me.

Comment: This solution worked for me, had two versions of python/anaconda installed in different directories for some reason.

Comment: I installed anaconda 3 and forgot about it. Never added it to path. Then I installed anaconda 3 at a different location. This was causing trouble when I tried to upgrade --all via conda. So I deleted the old anaconda directory. Went in to the the new anaconda prompt and everything is working as it should.

Answer (score 1):

**- In case someone is figuring a Quick-Fix for again able to download using conda:**

I've a exactly same issue while downloading packages using `conda install xyz` using "CMD" as well as "PowerShell" both. Tried a lot to figure out what was causing problem but couldn't get relevant help. However, just by-chance or hit & trial, I executed the command on "Anaconda PowerShell Prompt" and it worked! Don't know the exact problem but for now I'm ready to go ahead with my packages downloaded :)

Comment: Just come back here and was about to upvote this again :)

Answer (score 0):

This error can be caused if you compile your `dll` with one name and then change its name afterwards. I don't know why, but this was my problem. If you have changed the name try changing it back to its original name

Answer (score 0):

Problem coming only due to
OSGeo4W and QGIS installation
Uninstall this.
or reinstall with
Select Express Web-GIS Install and click next.
In the ‘Select Packages’ list, ensure that GDAL is selected; MapServer and Apache are also enabled by default, may be unchecked safely.

Answer (score -2):

I encountered the same problem on Win10. After updating python to 3.8 this problem disapeared.