# Loading dll using cytpes returns WinError 127

Tags: python-3.x, dll, ctypes

We use a python script to run a camera as part of an experiment. In practice, the python script uses `ctypes` to load a dll and this is what is used to access the camera functionality. We recently upgraded to a Windows 10 computer, and I now no longer seem to be able to load the dll.

A stripped down version of the relevant script as follows:

```
PARENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
os.add_dll_directory(PARENT_DIR)
x = ct_util.find_library('picam_64bit')
self.picam = ct.WinDLL(x)
```

On the fourth line, the following error is returned:

```
[WinError 127] The specified procedure could not be found
```

A few further notes:

- The camera works with the manufacturer-supplied executable.
- The code was originally written in Python 2.7 and has been migrated to Python 3.8. The same error occurs in both.
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627047/windowserror-error-127-the-specified-procedure-could-not-be-found) question is clearly relevant. I have made sure that only one version of Python is installed at a time (right now, 3.8), and there is only one version of the dll on the computer.
- The third line returns a sensible value, so Python can clearly `see' the DLL, just not load it.

Comment: Could be some dependency dll is missing. Use dependency walker to find the dependent dlls and make sure they are available in the same path.

Comment: `cd` to the directory where the DLL is, run Python, and directly load the DLL with `import ctypes;dll = ctypes.WinDLL('./picam_64bit')`.  Same error?

Comment: @adhilb ; Sorry for the delay, I have limited lab access at the moment. I have run the dependency walker and it flags up a number of missing dlls, but these are all api-ms-win and ext-ms-win dlls that are apparently not a problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36240215/dependency-walker-missing-dlls

Comment: @MarkTolonen, Yes, same error when I do that.

Comment: @adhilb ; I stand corrected. In addition to the api-ms-win dlls and ext-ms win dlls that are apparently not cause for concern, there are five missing dlls: GCBASE_MD_VC100_V2_4.DLL, GENAPI_MD_VC100_V2_4.DLL, HVSIFILETRUST.DLL, IESHIMS.DLL, LOG4CXX.DLL. Are these any cause for concern? Does the VC100 stand for some kind of visual C package?